# How to make label text centered in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Can we make label text  centered? I tried using text align but it only makes the hint text and input text centered, not the label text. here is my code:

```
TextFormField(
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
  // textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  decoration: InputDecoration(

    hintText: 'example@gmail.com',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(                      
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    alignLabelWithHint: true,
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
    color: Color(0xff9fe0ff),
    fontSize: 25,
  ),
  border: UnderlineInputBorder(
  borderSide: BorderSide(
  color: Color(0xff9fe0ff),
  ),
),
  labelText: 'Email',
),
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the default `TextFormField`. As you can see, there is an open issue for this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/2735.